# Use of the opening roll for corny/pointless exposition?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, cinema

(Please note - indeed [@Dan Bron](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/196495/44619) came up with the word *exposition*, which is now used to further clarify the question.)

---

There are many specific terms for different types of ***corny exposition*** in films.

For example a "pull-down-the-map" scene has a specific slang term, ***"the big board"***.

Sometimes the "corny exposition" is presented in textual form as a crawl...

[image: text "Salzburg, Austria, in the last Golden Days of the Thirties" over photograph of same]

[image: ...Early in the 21st Century, THE TYRELL CORPORATION advanced Robot evolution into the NEXUS phase -- a being virtually identical to a human -- known as a Replicant. The NEXUS 6 Replicants were superior in strength and agility, and at least equal in intelligence, to the genetic engineers who created them...]

[image: ... Special police squads -- BLADE RUNNER UNITS -- had orders to shoot ot kill, upon detection, any trespassing Replicant. This was not called execution. It was called retirement.]

Is there a term for using the crawl for corny exposition?

(Of course, a crawl need not be "corny" - in Star Wars the opening is generally well-loved!)

Comment: I think [*preamble,*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preamble) which you used in the question title, works very well.

Comment: Hey Andrew, sure, I'm wondering if there's a particular term for a preamble that is a "plot set-up" (not unlike the cliché "pull-down map" scene mentioned).  There's usually some specific sarcastic slang for such concepts in movies, such as, oh "title-drop" or "supporting actor", say.

Comment: { Just BTW, regarding crawls and cards .. the static ones are usually called "plates" and have been since they started using "plates" (ie, glass with paint on it) instead of "cards".  It's a bit like the way tech has changed with "filming" a shot, "taping" a shot, and today "recording" or "saving" a shot.  Of course, people sometimes still say "filming!" a shot although it really just goes on one of these .. http://www.panavision.za.com/news/solid-state-recorder.asp  Similarly, "crawl" is very rarely said, I'd say, for end titles etc - kids just say "scroll" or "text" you know. }

Comment: I am glad you chose to open a bounty. I *do* like this question but I still think the title needs tweaking.

Comment: Oh Jesus. I've just realized you cut out so much from the original. I was merely looking at the title. Now it's bare No, no, no... Talk about amputation.

Comment: Really, I prefer the short version, ML!  :)  Editing is good.  Actually the short version is much better!  I made it EVEN SHORTER.  Heh!

Comment: If you're happy, so am I.

Comment: LOL take it easy now  :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhH3mRkKDX8

Comment: @JoeBlow I like this title too, but I also liked the *On Poppy Hill* example for allowing spoken intros, like the Simpsons' ["The Bart Zone"](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/8F02.html) segment of ToHII, which satirizes *The Twilight Zone* and such openings with: "Presented for your consideration: Springfield. An average little town, with a not-so-average monster.... [This] particular monster can read minds, and if displeased, can turn people into grotesque walking terrors... And did I mention to you that the monster is a ten-year-old boy? Quite a twist, huh? Bet you didn't see that one coming."

Comment: an excellent example, @dingo!  :)  like I say Dan really found a fantastic list of industry terms, slang terms, for "all the various sorts of corny exposition"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general term for this is ***exposition***, and [TVTropes gives a long list of ways it's been achieved in film and fiction](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Exposition) (covering the methods you describe, and many more); the expositions that appear at the beginning of a work are usually qualified with "*opening*", as in "*[Opening Narration](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OpeningNarration)*", "*[Opening Monologue](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OpeningMonologue)*" (your *On Poppy Hill* examples), or "*[Opening Scroll](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OpeningScroll)*" (as in *Star Wars*).

That said, not all such introductory exposition is qualified with "opening"; the classic "pull down the map" trope is known as "***[The Big Board](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheBigBoard)***", and letting the scene speak for itself (as with the girl mysteriously doing chores alone) is known as "***[mise en scene](http://www.elementsofcinema.com/directing/mise-en-scene-in-films/)***", and the static text overlay you're primarily asking is simply known as a "***[title card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertitle)***" (or *intertitle*).

The difference between these latter modes of exposition and the former, which precludes them being qualified with "opening", is they can appear anywhere in the film where exposition is needed, not just at the very start.

Comment: aside -- GREAT work on "big board" I couldn't get that to my tongue either!

Comment: You know, brilliant on **exposition**, but it's hard to believe there isn't some term for "corny exposition", or "pointlessly explanatory exposition added by the producers" .. you know? Just as you hit the  nail on the head with 'big board', the usual slang for just exactly that scenic cliché. {For example: I swear, I was once reading something academic about Shakespeare, and it was referring to his "big board" moments .. even Shakespeare has crap expository passages!}

Comment: one of my buddies is a famous japanese director, and when he works in france he's like "What the hell am I, a miseensceneist?" :)

Comment: The problem is, for any given work or scene, or instance of a trope, you're likely to find some critics who consider it corny, and others brilliant. For that exact reason, trope names or film terms are meant to be descriptive, rather than editorial.  That said, scan through the list of expository tropes I linked to, and see if you can find one that suits.  If you do, add it as an answer, then accept it.

Comment: re your immediate comment there - for sure, the slang would be descriptive not necessarily pejorative.  (Just like "Big Board")  The list you link to on "TV Tropes" is remarkably useful! (Who knew!  Good old TV Tropes, we'll soon be referencing it in Physics Review papers). The rather modern "info dump" is helpful in describing this.  (e.g., "the ####ing producers put all the exposition in an info dump on a ####ing title card!").  Cheers again

Comment: Did you notice "*intro* dump" as well? That comes at the beginning; though it's more about introducing a large cast of characters (to potentially new audience members) than setting the scene.

Comment: fascinating!!  (Just on an unrelated note: you mention ticking an answer. It goes without saying I always tick answers (and usually add bounties), rest assured -- I guess, I suppose it's good form to **wait** a couple days to tick even the best answers, you know.  (unless you're like RobJohn on the math forum who just blows everyone away :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927637 )

Comment: @Joe, when I said "add it as an answer & accept it", I was referring to the situation where *you yourself* found the exact word you were looking for in the TVTropes list, so that no more searching need be done. I wasn't referring to ticking my answer. I'm honestly not in this for the points (you can't eat them, and there aren't many worthwhile privileges left to gain for me), so much as the thrill of the hunt. I agree with the general philosophy of leaving a question open a few days to attract more and better answers.

Comment: *Exposition is a literary tool that is used to give information to the audience through dialogue, description, flashback, or narrative.* This doesn't really seem to answer the question, as it refers to a wide range of things, including dialogue, per your source.

Comment: Dude I know you were just after moar points  :)  Lol got you now.

Comment: @medica, Joe described a similarly wide range of expository methods in his question, and I tried to address and identify each unique method he mentions (and I also tried to make clear that exposition is a general tool, though perhaps starting with "*The general word for this*" wasn't strong enough, even complemented by "*the expositions that appear at the beginning of a work are qualified with 'opening'*").

Comment: And now that you've pointed out the word is frickin' EXPOSITION, here's a funny blog note on excess-exposition in Comics: http://comiccoverage.typepad.com/comic_coverage/2008/01/great-moments-i.html

Comment: Your "opening monologue" and "opening scroll" have the same link. Love the *mise en scene* page by the way!

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Mari-LouA, fixed now. (And yay, I'm glad, I thought I was going to get flak for [technically improperly] describing "a girl cooking alone" as "mise en scene").

Answer (score 3):

George Lucas called it a [rollup](http://www.ssonlineuniverse.net/starwars/ANHScript.shtml).

Hampton Fancher and David Peoples [*Blade Runner*](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/blade-runner_shooting.html) didn't call it anything.

Peoples (the original screenwriter for Blade Runner, and who wrote the screenplay for Unforgiven) referred to the stills expositions in the *script* (which is full of technical information) for Unforgiven as [**crawl**](http://sfy.ru/?script=unforgiven)

A Glossary Of Screenwriting Terms & Filmmaking Definitions calls both types (still and moving) a [*crawl*](http://www.movieoutline.com/articles/a-glossary-of-screenwriting-terms-and-filmmaking-definitions.html).

> CRAWL
>   This is a term used for superimposed titles or text intended to move across/up/down/diagonally on screen. For example, the text at the beginning of Star Wars  movies "Crawls" up into infinity. Or, the written words "(crawl)" in Unforgiven.

So, I guess the disappointing answer is: a crawl.

Edited to add: the opening exposition in Blade Runner is, technically, a crawl.