# Information unavailable to the audience

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

What is it called when a character knows something the audience doesn't?

For example, if the character was stating something obvious like "today is your birthday", saying it only to inform the audience, what is that called?

Comment: If a character is only saying something to explain it to the audience, information the other characters should ostensibly know already, that's "***exposition***". For more details, you may be interested in [this answer to a related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196492/the-explanatory-textually-presented-preamble-on-a-film/196495#196495).

Comment: The most extreme form being the [*dramatic aside*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aside), where all pretext that the information is anything but exposition is abandoned.

Comment: Are you talking about lines like the commentary that Frank makes on _House of Cards_?

Comment: Note that - if I'm not mistaken - this has no connection at all to "dramatic irony".  I'm going to **boldly edit the question**, OP put it back if you want.  What do you reckon @DanBron.  TBC this is a nice question, OP, it just has nothing to do with "irony"

Comment: OP it could be you mean "breaking the fourth wall" ?  Google anywhere for it.

Comment: No: Socratic irony is when the audience knows something the character 'doesn't'.

Comment: And Socratic blarney is when Socrates endlessly protests that he really doesn't know anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

exposition ~ the act of expounding, setting forth, or explaining.